# How to pass data from @extends to @yield?

Tags: laravel

I have some common data getting from `helper`. Now I wanted to use that data in all over view. So, I am trying to declare that data in `app.blade.php` and trying to pass it's sections.

Here is my `app.blade.php` -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>ABC| @yield('title')</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ asset('/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('/assets/abc/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <?php 
        //get theme
        $theme = AppHelper::instance()->getTheme();

        //get theme folder
        $themeFolder = $theme[0]->websiteAdmin;

        //set include files section path
        $includePath = 'frontend.'.$theme[0]->themeName.'.sections.';
    ?>
</head>
@yield('content')
</html>
```

Here I want to pass variables `$theme, $themefolder, $includePath` to `@yield('content')`.

I tried below code -

```
@yield('content', array('theme'=> $theme, 'themeFolder'=> $themeFolder, 'includePath'=> $includePath))
```

But getting error that those variables are undefined.

```
Undefined variable: theme
```

Can you please help me how to pass data from @extend to @yield?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use View composers to accomplish this. They allow you to pass the same data across multiple views by only calling it in one place.

In your `providers/AppServiceProvider.php` you can add the following to your boot method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View; //import view facade

public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(['view-name', 'another-view-name'], function($view){

            $theme = AppHelper::instance()->getTheme();
            $themeFolder = $theme[0]->websiteAdmin;
            $includePath = 'frontend.'.$theme[0]->themeName.'.sections.';

            $view->with(compact('themeFolder', 'includePath', 'theme'));
        });

    }
```

`View::composers` first argument takes an array of views, put all the views you want to pass the data to here `['view-name', 'another-view-name']`, it can also take a single string.

The data will now be available to your specified views through `$themeFolder` `$includePath` and `$theme` variables

If you want this data to pass to ALL views, you can do `'*'` as the first argument. 
**NOTE**, this will pass the data to EVERY view you create, only do `'*'` if you want every view to contain the data! Otherwise, specifiy the views individually.

If you want all the views within a certain folder to get passed the data you can do `'folder-name.*'`.

Alternatively, the only other way to pass data to your `@yield` is to return the view `app.blade.php` with the variables in your controller.